# Google Sheets Api Instead of having a .json file attacted, embed it in python code

Tags: javascript, python, json, security, bson

Hey everyone I was wondering if I can embed a .json file into my python file so instead of having a separate .py and .json file, i was wondering if I could take the info from my .json file and add it into my python file without losing its function.

this is the .JSON FILE

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----- ...",
  "client_id": "11...",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
}
```

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("json_data", scope)

creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("json_data", scope)

This is how its normally used from a file name Im wondering if there is a way to call it without having a seperate file

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow. It's a little difficult to identify exactly what you're asking: if you want just that specific data (which will remain unchanged) then it is already in a Python dictionary format so can simply be added to your file as a dictionary variable. However, since you are reading it from a file into `creds`, a dictionary is unlikely to play nicely. Why exactly do you need it to be in the same file? That might help us determine what you should do.

Comment: @JackParkinson the code needs the data inside of the json file to operate and I need it to be in the same file because then i could convert all of it into a .exe file